# SoapUI Groovy script: Create new project using command line

Tags: groovy, soapui, test-runner

I am trying to create Soapui project using groovy script.
When running it directly from SoapUI, the Script is working correctly and new Project with WSDL is created.

The script is created in: *Project -> TestSuite -> TestCase -> Groovy script*

```
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.*  
import com.eviware.soapui.impl.WsdlInterfaceFactory

String Release = "xxx.yyy";
String projectName = "Test_$Release" + ".xml";
String projectPath = "D:/work/";
String fullProjectPath = "$projectPath$projectName";
String pathToWSDL = "D:/work/AWSECommerceService.wsdl.xml";
log.info ("Release value is $Release");
log.info ("Projet path is $projectPath");
log.info ("Project name is $projectName");
log.info ("pathToWSDL $pathToWSDL");
log.info ("fullProjectPath $fullProjectPath");

def currentProject = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project;

WsdlProject project = currentProject
                        .getWorkspace()
                        .createProject(projectName, new File(fullProjectPath));
 WsdlInterface iface = WsdlInterfaceFactory.importWsdl(project,pathToWSDL, true )[0]
context.testCase.testSuite.project.save("");
```

The script is working correctly when from `SoapUI`. But, failing when run it using `testrunner.bat` as given below:

```
testrunner.bat "D:\Ivo\Project.xml"
```

It is returning following error:

> Error:java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method createProject() on null object

Comment: Hi,

I’m not sure about the error, but I’m curious as to why you’re trying to script project creation when running a test?

Comment: Hi, After each new release of application, we have to use new wsdls when testing web services. there are 6 wsdls, security option endpoints... we want to avoid setting all these things manually

Comment: Is entire wsdl changes each release?

Comment: @Rao: Yes, that is possible and our requirement for testing. Sorry for asking, but why are you asking :)? Do you suggest different approach?

Comment: @ivanz, just to understand the case. I understand that there can be minor changes for certain operations usually where you can directly update the wsdl. Any ways, try the solution below to see if that helps to over come the above mentioned issue.

Comment: You can simply update the WSDL’s from the menu.  SoapUI will go back to original location of the WSDL and update the endpoints based on that.

Comment: It seems as though you are creating a whole new project for a iteration/release.  I’d suggest not doing this.

Comment: Wsdls for each release are on new location. E.g.: D:\Releases\{release}\Wsdl\  and i have to use these new ones each time. Even though usually there are no changes or no changes in wsdls

Comment: OK, I'm still struggling to understand why create a whole new project.  Even with a new project, you're still going to have migrate your tests from project at iteration -1 to your new project in order to run tests.  Updating WSDL's isn't too big a task, especially when compared to porting your old tests over.  Please don't think I am criticising, I just want to understand why.

Comment: For the appI am working on, I'm still using the original SoapUI 'project' that I created 14 releases ago.  Obviously, the tests have evolved an awful lot since release one.  When I have a new release, I run the same tests.  When functionality has been modified, I re-factor the necessary tests.  For new functionality, I create new tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try change as given below:

**From:**

```
WsdlProject project = currentProject
                        .getWorkspace()
                        .createProject(projectName, new File(fullProjectPath));
```

**To:**

```
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject();
project.setName(projectName);
//your statements goes here
//finally save project
project.saveAs(fullProjectPath);
```

Comment: This is returning following error: 09:00:25,367 INFO  [SoapUI] File [C:\work\Test_xxx.yyy.xml] does not exist, trying URL instead
09:00:25,369 ERROR [SoapUI] An error occurred [unknown protocol: c], see error log for details
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: c

Comment: @ivanz, Updated the answer under `To`, can you give it a try now?